# How to write a list from an output in a message box usin wx python?

Tags: python

we can write in a messsage box using

```
    msg = "Hello World"
    dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, msg, "About", wx.OK)
    dlg.showmodal()
    dlg.Destroy()
```

now the problem is writing a list using msg = list...
where list is our output that we want to display in the msg box.

i am geting an error that "string or unicode type required"

Comment: So you want a list produced from some process displayed in the message box?

Comment: yes i want that list in message box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message in a message box must be a string.  Thus a list must be converted to a string.  There is more than one way of doing this, but my recommendation is to do this.

```
mylist = ['blah', 7, 'etc...']
#make sure the values are strings
mylist = [str(x) for x in mylist]
msg = ', '.join(mylist)

dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, msg, "About", wx.OK)
dlg.showmodal()
dlg.Destroy()
```

If you don't want a comma replace it with something else.  You could even to this if you want the output to be one line per item in list.

```
msg = '\n'.join(mylist)
```

I think that's what your after.

Comment: got another error: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found

Comment: mylist = [('23','456'), ('678','1123'), . . .]

Comment: You did do mylist = [str(x) for x in mylist] didn't you?

Comment: The logic works in pull down menu of the GUI. But when i run the same logic in my custom buttons(bind in the panel) it doesnot work without giving any error.